# What we can say about these two elements $x= yxy^{-1} $?

Tags: group-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ are two elements of some group with relation $x = yxy^{-1}$. What we can say about $x$ and $y$?

I can say that $x$ and $y$ commute because $xy = yx$. What are other things we can say about $x$ and $y$? I think we can't say that $y$ is self-conjugate.

A element $x$ is said to be self conjugate if $\forall y \in G, x = yxy^{-1}$

Comment: What do you mean by an element being self-conjugate? You have used it in another question as well, but it is not as far as I know a standard term.

Comment: An element is ""self-conjugate"" with your definition iff it commutes with every other element.

Comment: The condition written there is called being central.

Comment: @ Najib Idrissi Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say anything that follows just from the fact that they commute, and nothing else without more information.

Comment: Even I put one condition that $G$ is finite.

Comment: @ddddd You have written up a condition that is equivalent to the elements commuting, How could you ever conclude anything more then?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can* say that $y$ *is* self-conjugate, since that holds for *any* element of *any* group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Right. I have deleted that.